# How to choose between oauth and saml

Tags: oauth2, saml

I need to push data from external system to salesforce. External system has got lot of communities with it. Each community should be linked with a salesforce org. We do have apex classes to pull data from external system using the community Id stored in custom settings.

This needs to be developed as managed package in Salesforce.

So the external system should use oauth or saml to push data to different salesforce orgs?? Please advise on the different flows. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Either should work just fine.

My Personal choice would be oAuth because of simplicity and there are lot of examples available. Also for SAML you need CA signed certificate.

Here are main differences between SAML and oAuth:

SAML has one feature that OAuth2 lacks: the SAML token contains the user identity information (because of signing). With OAuth2, you don't get that out of the box, and instead, the Resource Server needs to make an additional round trip to validate the token with the Authorization Server.

On the other hand, with OAuth2 you can invalidate an access token on the Authorization Server, and disable it from further access to the Resource Server.

Both approaches have nice features and both will work for SSO. We have proved out both concepts in multiple languages and various kinds of applications. At the end of the day OAuth2 seems to be a better fit for our needs (since there isn't an existing SAML infrastructure in place to utilize).

OAuth2 provides a simpler and more standardized solution which covers all of our current needs and avoids the use of workarounds for interoperability with native applications.

More details: http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/

Comment: agree with you.Oauth is simple as compared to SAML.